# Persist angular application state to external database

Tags: angular, state, persist

I have complex angular application with many components, I am using reactive forms.

When user is done finishing different UI screens (around 10 different tabs), they can press "Save" button which will trigger the business process in the backend. User has to finish all tabs and hit the Save. Problem with this approach is that sometimes users want to take a break and when they come back, they will have to redo everything.

I would like to give them option to save their work so they can come back and continue where they left.

My problem is that this application is now very complex, many components interacting with each other, validating input provided by other components/fields, calculating/retrieving data from API and populating other fields.

What is the best technical approach to save entire state of the application to external data source and reload it when user comes back and want to start where they left?

Basically I am looking for a way to freeze current state of application and rehydrate it at some later point in time.

Comment: Use browser local storage to store user previous activities.

Comment: If you use a state management library (like ngrx) you could save the entire state of the app quite easily in local storage with a meta reducer. Would only be a few lines